# Google Earth Engine: error when extracting pixels values of chlorophyll and SST for specific coordinates from SMI Modis Aqua

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, value-extraction

I'm trying to extract specific pixel values in a csv table of **chlorophyll-a** and **sea surface temperature** from *Standard Mapped Image MODIS Aqua Data* to match to the sampling site over the sampling period that on site measurements were also taken.
The script below returns an error **sitesCollection.filterBounds is not a function**. Any idea how I can fix this error?

I have run this code before with *GCOM-C/SGLI L3 Chlorophyll-a concentration (V3)* and I don't get the error. The only issue is I get a lot of NAs with that dataset and therefore I switched to *Standard Mapped Image MODIS Aqua Data*.

This is the code:

```
// Extract sea water chlorophyll-a and SST values for at a specific pixel that match to the 
// sampling site AND sampling period that on-site sampling was done

// Import dataset

var sitesCollection = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI')
  // Filter dates
  .filterDate('2022-01-10', '2022-02-10')
  // Mosaic all images in the collection (could use .mean() or .median())
  .mosaic()
  // Select only the two bands of interest
  .select(['chlor_a', 'sst']);

var chlorsst =
sitesCollection.select(['chlor_a', 'sst']);
var chlorsstVis = {
min: 0.0,
max: 99,
};

Map.addLayer(chlorsst, chlorsstVis,'Chlorsst');
 
print(chlorsst)

// Study sites sampled 

var siteCoords_features = [
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(73.8918, 1.8119), {name: 'TRA01'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(72.7300, -4.5690), {name: 'TRA02'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(72.2303, -5.2986), {name: 'TRA03'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(72.2571, -5.2814), {name: 'SPOU2000'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(72.2360371, -5.340068), {name: 'SAIN2000'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(72.204352, -5.324261), {name: 'SAOU2000'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(72.250802, -5.321385), {name: 'SPIN2000'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(71.95208, -5.36914), {name: 'PGCIN2000'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(71.770524, -5.399835), {name: 'PPOIN2000'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(71.808373, -5.424579), {name: 'TRA04'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(71.7319344, -5.400639), {name: 'PPOOU2000'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(71.351852, -6.182962), {name: 'GE2000'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(71.495025, -6.151137), {name: 'TRA05'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(71.541092, -6.157744), {name: 'TRA07'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(71.250083, -6.389199), {name: 'GD2000'}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(72.419197, -7.246325), {name: 'DE2000'}),];

// Create a FeatureCollection from the list of coords
var pt_collection = ee.FeatureCollection(siteCoords_features);

print('List', pt_collection);
Map.addLayer(pt_collection);
Map.centerObject(pt_collection, 10);

// Pixel extractions of all coordinates

var outputData = pt_collection.map(function(feat){
  // only map over images that intersect with the selected feature.
  var filterCollect = sitesCollection.filterBounds(ee.Feature(feat).geometry());
  
  return filterCollect.map(function(img){
    return ee.Feature(null,img.reduceRegion({
      geometry: feat.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()})).set({ // set additional properties
        name: feat.get('name'),
        //date: feat.get('Date'),
        lat: feat.geometry().coordinates().get(0),
        lon: feat.geometry().coordinates().get(1),
      });
    });
}).flatten();

print(outputData);

// Export
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: outputData,
  folder: 'GEE_results',
  fileNamePrefix: 'MODIS_chloro_sst_2022',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `var filterCollect = sitesCollection.filterBounds(ee.Feature(feat).geometry());`

to `var filterCollect = ee.ImageCollection(sitesCollection).filterBounds(ee.Feature(feat).geometry());`

and it looks good now. When in doubt, tell GEE what object type you're using

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`mosaic`: This function transforms  ImageCollection into a single image, so you can not use the function `map`, you can delete it.